# The counter script should be running when the scroll reaches it ( JS), how can i make it?

Tags: javascript

The task is to make a counter script on the site, I sort of managed to implement the counter script, but now I need it to work by scrolling. Help please, how can I add a scrolling event to this counter script so that it fires 1 time when I scroll to it?

========================================================================

```js
  const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
    counters.forEach((number) => {
    number.innerHTML = "0";

        const updateCounter = () => {
            const target = +number.getAttribute("data-target");
            const c = +number.innerText;

            if (c < target) {
                number.innerText = c + 1;
                setTimeout(updateCounter, 100);
            } else {
                number.innerText = target;
            }
        };
        updateCounter();
    })
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: gray;
 margin: 20px auto;
}

.long-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-count {
  max-width: 324px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-count__title {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.number-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.thousand {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #c40b0b;
}

.number {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 96px;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #c40b0b;
}

.form-count__text {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<p class="long-text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo.


Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
</p>

<div class="form-count" id="box">
  <div class="number-wrap">
    <div id="showScroll" class="number" data-target="17">                </div>
    <span class="thousand">k</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick for you will be [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

You can see that I added an Observer for the `number` items
and when they appear 100% in the viewport you the counter will start.
It will also stop the moment you scroll out of the viewport event partially.
This is due to the `threshold` being set to 1.0. You can play with it as you need

```js
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.number');

const updateCounter = (number, e) => {
  const target = +number.getAttribute("data-target");
  const c = +number.innerText;

  if (c < target && e.intersectionRatio === 1) {
    number.innerText = c + 1;
    setTimeout(() => updateCounter(number, e), 100);
  }
};


function createObserver(number) {
  let observer;

  let options = {
    threshold: 1
  };

  observer = new IntersectionObserver(([e]) => updateCounter(number, e), options);
  observer.observe(number);
}

counters.forEach(number => {
  number.innerHTML = "0";
  createObserver(number)
})
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: gray;
 margin: 20px auto;
}

.long-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-count {
  max-width: 324px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-count__title {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.number-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.thousand {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #c40b0b;
}

.number {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 96px;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #c40b0b;
}

.form-count__text {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<p class="long-text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo.


Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illoLorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint enim non animi nam aliquid repudiandae vel quod quaerat? Quasi maiores reprehenderit minus deserunt deleniti illo
</p>

<div class="form-count" id="box">
  <div class="number-wrap">
    <div id="showScroll" class="number" data-target="17">                </div>
    <span class="thousand">k</span>
  </div>
</div>
```